# Date range picker directive with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having problems with date range picker directive and custom and ranges, i have modified the original https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker the directive to this:

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('ngBootstrap', []).directive('input', function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModel) {
            if ($attributes.type !== 'daterange') return;

            var options = {};
            options.format = $attributes.format || 'YYYY-MM-DD';
            options.separator = $attributes.separator || ' - ';
            options.minDate = $attributes.minDate && moment($attributes.minDate);
            options.maxDate = $attributes.maxDate && moment($attributes.maxDate);
            options.dateLimit = $attributes.limit && moment.duration.apply(this, $attributes.limit.split(' ').map(function (elem, index) { return index === 0 && parseInt(elem, 10) || elem; }) );
            options.ranges = $attributes.ranges && $parse($attributes.ranges)($scope);

            function format(date) {
                return date.format(options.format);
            }

            function formatted(dates) {
                return [format(dates.startDate), format(dates.endDate)].join(options.separator);
            }

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue) return '';
                return modelValue;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                return viewValue;
            });

            ngModel.$render = function () {
                if (!ngModel.$viewValue || !ngModel.$viewValue.startDate) return;
                $element.val(formatted(ngModel.$viewValue));
            };

            $scope.$watch($attributes.ngModel, function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue || (!modelValue.startDate)) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue({ startDate: moment().startOf('day'), endDate: moment().startOf('day') });
                    return;
                }
                $element.data('daterangepicker').startDate = modelValue.startDate;
                $element.data('daterangepicker').endDate = modelValue.endDate;
                $element.data('daterangepicker').updateView();
                $element.data('daterangepicker').updateCalendars();
                $element.data('daterangepicker').updateInputText();
            });

            $element.daterangepicker(options, function(start, end) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue({ startDate: start, endDate: end });
                    ngModel.$render();
                });
            });         
        }
    };
});

})(angular);
```

to allow declarations like:

```
<date-range-picker ng-model="dateRange"
                   class="pull-right"
                   style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"
                   min-date="{{minDate}}"
                   max-date="{{maxDate}}"
                   ranges="{'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                            'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')],
                            'Last 3 Months': [moment().subtract('month', 3).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]}">
    <i class="fontello-icon-calendar-alt-1"></i>
    <span>....</span>


    <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 8px"></b>
</date-range-picker>
```

Selecting custom range with the 2 calendars work fine as the original directive but the problem comes up when selecting one of the predefined ranges. 
Can anybody give me a help with this?.

UPDATE:

**I HAVE FIXED THE PROBLEM**, it worked this way:

```
<date-range-picker ng-model="dateRange"
                               class="pull-right"
                               style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc"
                               ng-model="dateRange"
                               ranges="dateRange.ranges"
                               >
                <i class="fontello-icon-calendar-alt-1"></i>
                <span></span>
                <b class="caret" style="margin-top: 8px"></b>
</date-range-picker>
```

With this minimum changes on the directive:

```
((angular) ->
  "use strict"
  angular.module("directives.daterangepicker", []).directive "dateRangePicker", ($compile, $parse) ->
    restrict: "E"
    require: "ngModel"
    link: ($scope, $element, $attributes, ngModel) ->
      format = (date) ->
        date.format options.format
      formatted = (dates) ->
        [format(dates.startDate), format(dates.endDate)].join options.separator
      options = {}
      options.format = $attributes.format or "MMM D, YYYY"
      options.separator = $attributes.separator or " - "
      options.opens = $attributes.opens or "left"
      options.minDate = $attributes.minDate and moment($attributes.minDate)
      options.maxDate = $attributes.maxDate and moment($attributes.maxDate)
      options.dateLimit = $attributes.limit and moment.duration.apply(this, $attributes.limit.split(" ").map((elem, index) ->
        index is 0 and parseInt(elem, 10) or elem
      ))
      options.ranges = $attributes.ranges and $parse($attributes.ranges)($scope)
      ngModel.$formatters.unshift (modelValue) ->
        return ""  unless modelValue
        modelValue

      ngModel.$parsers.unshift (viewValue) ->
        viewValue

      ngModel.$render = ->
        return  if not ngModel.$viewValue or not ngModel.$viewValue.startDate
        $element.find("span").html(formatted(ngModel.$viewValue))

      $scope.$watch $attributes.ngModel, (modelValue) ->
        if not modelValue or (not modelValue.startDate)
          ngModel.$setViewValue
            startDate: moment().startOf("day")
            endDate: moment().startOf("day")

          return
        $element.data("daterangepicker").startDate = modelValue.startDate
        $element.data("daterangepicker").endDate = modelValue.endDate
        $element.data("daterangepicker").minDate = modelValue.minDate
        $element.data("daterangepicker").maxDate = modelValue.maxDate
        $element.data("daterangepicker").updateView()
        $element.data("daterangepicker").updateCalendars()
        #$element.data("daterangepicker").updateInputText()

      $element.daterangepicker options, (start, end) ->
        alert "$apply#{moment(start).toDate()}"
        alert options.maxDate
        $scope.$apply ->
          ngModel.$setViewValue
            startDate: start
            endDate: end

          ngModel.$render()



) angular
```

Comment: what do you mean selecting one of the intervals? And what is the problem exactly

Comment: but what is the problem?

Comment: The predefined ranges are links are not working, they don't select the date range correctly and all the three ranges get highlighted on the dropdown list, i don't know if the cause is the bindings or something else.

Comment: Found the problem and updated the question, ranges and ng-model attributes needs to be backed by the controller as showed on the original component URL: http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue you describe: Date ranges are all highlighted by default and all represent the same date range (today), although they vary significantly (this year, last month etc...) I've backed the component properly by providing dateRange and dateRange.ranges in the model, but still can't seem to fix it. What exactly did you change in the controller code? I can't seem to find the difference. Thanks